# Why Unsynchronized ArrayList Object add method is not behaving properly

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist, addition

Here is the sample code

1) ArrayList is a single object which is passed to every thread of ThreadPool.

2) At end of execution list size should be 50, if you check the sample outputs its may not 50. Sometime it may be 41 or 47 like that, why it is behaving like that.

```
public class Test {

    ArrayList list=new ArrayList();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService executorService3 = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(10);
        Test test=new Test();
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            Mythread t1=new Mythread(test.list);

            executorService3.execute(t1);
        }

        executorService3.shutdown();

        while(executorService3.isShutdown())
        {
            //---This is not giveging proper output as expected is 50.--
            System.out.println("List size="+test.list.size());
            break;
        }
    }
}


class Mythread implements Runnable {

    List list=null;
    Mythread(List list) {
        this.list=list;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
            this.list.add(i);   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `Mythread` class is not a thread.  It's confusing to see "thread" in its name.  The generic name for things that you submit to an `ExecutorService` is "task".  `MyTask` would be a better name for the class.

Comment: Q: What is the `while` loop in your `main()` routine supposed to accomplish?  `executorService3.isShutdown()` will return `true` the first time and every time it's called because your main thread shut the service down on the line above.  Maybe you should be using `executorService3.awaitTermination()`.

Comment: Q: Did you mean to write "asynchronized" in your question title? or was that a typo?  Your threads certainly do _not_ use synchronization when accessing the `List`, but "asynchronized" is an unconventional way to write it.  Most people would say "unsynchronized" or "not synchronized."  The difference is, "asynchronized" makes it sound like you actively _did_ something to remove synchronization, whereas "unsynchronized" is more passive (i.e., you left it out.)

Comment: Re, "At end of execution list size should be 50"  Well actually, since your code allows several threads to update the list without synchronization, you should _not_ expect that outcome.  You might get that outcome if you change your code to wait for all of the tasks to terminate before it checks the length of the list, but it's not _guaranteed_ to get that outcome.

Comment: This program should be expected to make evil things happen, because it's modifying a list without any kind of synchronization.  You should _expect_ the result to be screwy.

Comment: Hi Vojtech Ruzicka, Thanks for your reply Reply for 1) YES Mythread class is not thread instance is a instance of Runnable. For the shake of ExecutorService i created it.

Comment: 2) While Loop inside of main() method is responsible to create multiple threads by invoking the Mythread t1=new Mythread(test.list);

            executorService3.execute(t1);, Yes i used executorService3.awaitTermination() statement but still some times, the List size is 50.

Comment: 3) I accept your statement, what i mean here is i don't want to synchronized the List

Comment: "I don't want to synchronized the list" nobody is making you; but you just can't expect it to behave like you have synchronized it if you don't.

Answer (score 2):

Your code isn't waiting for the threads to finish execution. By the time your code calls the following line

```
System.out.println("List size="+test.list.size());
```

there's no guarantee that they have finished, and so no guarantee that the list contains the expected 50 items. Use the awaitTermination method (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)), e.g.:

```
executorService3.shutdown();
executorService3.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
System.out.println("List size="+test.list.size());
```

(Exception handling omitted for brevity)

Comment: Exactly i feel the same, but in this case if you look at my code  while(executorService3.isShutdown()) // it return true when it turn off right?
        { }

Comment: Hi Gothytim, i have tried with executorService3.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS); by increasing the waiting time, BUT still getting same unexpected SIZE of ArrayList

Answer (score 2):

As it says in the [Javadoc for `ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html):

> **Note that this implementation is not synchronized**. If multiple threads access an ArrayList instance concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the list structurally, it *must* be synchronized externally.

So it's "not behaving properly" because you're not using it as described in the documentation.

As is suggested in the Javadoc, you can wrap your `list` in a synchronized list:

```
List<Integer> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
```

Comment: I love this answer thaks Andy Turner.  Conclusion is :-- When 2 or more threads tries modifies the list structure concurrently that list should be  "Synchronized"

Comment: That is exactly what the quote from the documentation says, so, yes. Aside from the fact that it is "at least one", not "2 or more".

Comment: Read the quote. It is all in there.

Comment: "At least one" is a mathematical term meaning one or more.  the statement is "At least one of the threads modifies". What my Question is in case of one thread what is the need of Synchronization.

Comment: I got it,  it's not "At least one of the thread modifies" it is "At least one of the threads modifies"

Answer (score 0):

It's a concurrency problem.
The way i see it, you have :
5 threads that will execute the run method on the same object. Multiple threads can insert a variable, on the same position in the array list, since it is not synchronized.
Could you print the content of your list ?

Comment: Hi Bob thanks for reply, i think you are wrong, that "Multiple thread can increment the i variable" --- Here i variabe is inside run() method of Mythread class, and Mythread object creation is inside main method for loop.